# Rails PG Hartl Tutorial error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am doing the Hartl Tutorial and have gotten to the step for deployment to Heroku. I am getting this error when installing the pg gem. I have already tried to run the --without production command, but I am still getting this error. I copy and pasted my gem file from his so I know there isn't an error in syntax.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
--with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby
--with-pg
--without-pg
--with-pg-config
--without-pg-config
--with-pg_config
--without-pg_config
--with-pg-dir
--without-pg-dir
--with-pg-include
--without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
--with-pg-lib
--without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/pg-    0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/KohlKohlbrenner/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-    13/2.1.0-static/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing pg (0.17.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.17.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Do you have PostgreSQL installed on your local machine?

Comment: no I don't and I don't use postgresql efficiently enough to have it installed so that is why I am trying to include the gem

Comment: Show your `Gemfile`, please.

Comment: You need to have PostgreSQL (including the development packages) installed before you can build the `pg` gem, you need to have `pg` if you want to use PostgreSQL in your development environment.

Comment: @muistooshort, At that stage of the tutorial, the tutorial does not use the pg gem in development.

Comment: **I have already tried to run the --without production command,** There's no such command.  You need to include the exact command that produces the error.  Errors without commands or commands without errors are useless.  And if you ask questions pertaining to gems in your rails project, it is mandatory that you post your Gemfile.